# iOS Positioning fix

Tags: javascript, ios, css, position

I've been editing a site for a friend, updating it etc, I changed an old Flash script slideshow to a JS one.
It runs fine, but when loaded into an iPhone/iPod, the entire section containing the slideshow & text loads incorrectly, underneath the Left Panel, instead of next to it.
The site loads fine on several Android devices, & PC browsers.

Any ideas on what's wrong/how I can fix it?
http://www.stonehouserestaurant.com.au

Thanks, Matt.

Comment: I think it's because the footer of the right side is too long, that's why it's floating under the left side. On the mobile you can see that the footer is longer than on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The footer of the right side is longer on the mobile website than on the browserwebsite. That's why it's floating under the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Give the html a max width:

```
html {max-width: 1024px;}
```

Though it will look like it should you still have amount of space...scroll..i think you should check your whole content to see whats happening..